# how to display image side by side using css?

Tags: html, css

see the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jrd6.png)

I tried flex lef and  display:inline-block but didn't work.

here is my css:

```
.previwimage{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #524eb7;
    border-radius: 10px;
     
    
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your HTML,

but I think you can place the images within the same div

and set up a grid layout.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="example.com/img1.png" alt="my first image" >
  <img src="example.com/img2.png" alt="my second image">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
}
```